# angular unit testing - why underscores help keep code clean? Are they necessary?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

From the docs:

> Underscore notation: The use of the underscore notation (e.g.:
>   _$rootScope_) is a convention wide spread in AngularJS community to keep the variable names clean in your tests. That's why the $injector
>   strips out the leading and the trailing underscores when matching the
>   parameters. The underscore rule applies only if the name starts and
>   ends with exactly one underscore, otherwise no replacing happens.

Is there anything bad that can happen if someone omits underscores? Can someone help explain how this is cleaner? Just looking to better understand and when I was reviewing a passing test that didn't use underscores and I could not explain to myself the why's here and if anything unexpected can happen if omitted.

Snippet of code from test

```
 var testScope, rootScope;
 var state,log;

  beforeEach(module('test'));

 beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, MonitoringService) {
  testScope = $rootScope.$new();
  rootScope = $rootScope;
  state = $state;
  log = $log;


 testController = $controller('TestController', {
   $rootScope: rootScope,
   $state: state,
   MonitoringService: MonitoringService,
  });
```

So in this test (didn't copy whole thing) the test passes and monitoring service is injected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine not to use the underscore notation.  It is there so that you can name test variables with the same names as the things that are being injected (Primarily, for things included by the Angular framework). For example with `$q`:

```
var $q;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, MonitoringService, _$q_) {
  testScope = $rootScope.$new();
  rootScope = $rootScope;
  state = $state;
  log = $log;
  $q = _$q_;
```

It can be harder to read if `$q` is named something like `q` in the test class.  Using the underscore notation keeps tests clean because the developer doesn't have to map back and forth between Angular and local test names.

However, if you want different names then there is no conflict and you can safely ignore the underscore notation.

Comment: so just to be certain I understand...the confusion being if your var is name $q and your injecting $q that is what underscores try to prevent?

Comment: Exactly. In fact, if you tried without undertakes, you'd be assigning the function parameter to itself.